# strip all timestamps from a local git repository

Tags: git, git-branch

i have a local git repository, ie it is not shared on a server or something, and only one person (me) has committed into it. Now i want to share the repo, but there is a problem:

Too much information is encoded in form of commit-timestamps. Others could reconstruct when and for how long i was working on the repository.

This is  violation of our policy, apparently.

So i am looking for a way to reset all timestamps in my repository to an invalid date.

I tried some trickery with branch filters, but it didnt quiet work out. :(

Comment: That's a strange policy. Instead of using an "invalid" date, you should be able to use `filter-branch` to set all of your timestamps to, for example, today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=2014-01-25T15:00:00
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=2014-01-25T15:00:00'
```

`git filter-branch` goes through all commits and the `--env-filter` argument specifies that you will be changing the environment in which the commits were made.

The command above should do the trick for resetting all dates to today.

Comment: yes, that did the trick. I was missing the "export". Can you elaborate on what exactly that does? Docs are confusing.

Comment: `export` is the bash command that sets environment variables and marks them to be passed to child processes